# How do i fix this code? for some reason it only does the first if statement and disregards every other if/else lines

Tags: python

The first clause of the if statement is the only clause it looks at, and disregards every other part of the if clause.

```
def split(word):
    return[char for char in word]

prefix1 = "pan"
prefix2 = "pam"
prefix3 = "pang"
prefix4 = "pang-"


word = input()
a = (split(word))

if a[0] == "d" or "l" or "r" or "s" or "t":
    print(prefix1+word)

elif a[0] == "p" or "b":
    print(prefix2+word)

elif a[0] == "a" or "e" or "i" or "o" or "u":
    print(prefix4+word)

else:
    print(prefix3+word)
```

Comment: The proximal issue here, as pointed out below - but just to underscore - is that `if a == b or c` means `(if a == b) or (if c)` not `(if a == b) or (if a == c)`.

Answer (score 2):

The correct test for what you want should be:

```
if a[0] == "d" or a[0] == "l" or a[0] == "r" or ...:
```

(need to repeat the `a[0] ==`)
Otherwise, after the `or` you're testing if a simple character string is a True expression, with is actually true in Python.

You can avoid repeating the `a[0] ==` by checking if it matches any character in a list like this:

```
if a[0] in ["d", "l", "r", "s", "t"]:
```

Comment: yep i realized that and i did it already tysm

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
prefix1 = "pan"
prefix2 = "pam"
prefix3 = "pang"
prefix4 = "pang-"


word = input()
first_char = word[0]

mapping = {
    "dlrst": prefix1,
    "pb": prefix2,
    "aeiou": prefix3
}
def get_prefix(char):
    for k, v in mapping.items():
        if char in k:
            return v
    return prefix4

expected = get_prefix(first_char) + word
print(expected)
```